# Select 1 row multiple time if has more then 1 value in other column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database structure. The issue is that the table is really complex (typo3).

I will simplify to this:

```
|     ID   |CAT  | 
|==========|=====|
|1         |44,15|
|2         |16   |
|3         |29,30|
```

What I want to have as a result is 1 row for each CATEGORY (CAT), it mean

```
1 44
1 15
2 16
3 29
3 30
```

I tried to use simple select but of course it does not work.

I also tried to use a left join with the table CATEGORY using `CATEGORY.id IN (TABLE1.cat)`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: The real sql is very long to put here but i tried to put what i did in the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

**1.:** You DB structure is bad! It not even First Normal Form (1NF), because you have an array in a column as string representation.

**2.:** It's not that tricky.

Some inspiration: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/ or here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Yes i confirm that the base structure is bad as normally it's a many to many relation but i have to deal with :(

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two values in cat:

```
select id, left(cat, locate(',', cat) - 1)
from t
where cat like '%,%'
union all
select id, substr(cat, locate(',', cat) + 1, length(cat))
from t
where cat like '%,%'
union all
select id, cat
from t
where cat not like '%,%'
```

If you have a list of categories, then you can do the following:

```
select t.id, c.cat
from t join
     categories c
     on concat(',', c.cat, ',') like concat('%,', t.cat, ',%')
```